# I want to know how law of conservation of energy holds in the generation of electricity in dams?

Tags: homework-and-exercises, fluid-dynamics, newtonian-gravity, energy-conservation, dissipation

Basically law of conservation states that input energy is equal to the output energy. But i was wondering that in case of generating electricity in dams no input energy is required. As the dam only collects the water and then the water is made to fall on the turbine from a height in order to generate electricity. But can any one explain how the law of conservation holds here.
Please let me know if i am wrong somewhere.

Comment: Are you thinking that the system only includes the dam? Doesn't the water that falls leave the outlet near the bottom of the dam with less energy than it had at the inlet near the top of the dam?

Comment: Have you learned about gravitational potential energy?

Comment: The main reason to ask this question was that the electricity generated is not compromised in any way i.e is there any loss in the electricity generated or the whole electricity generated is passed to the grid.

Comment: Have you read anything about energy and work? Have you read about sources of energy or different forms of energy?

Comment: I’m voting to close this question because of the apparent lack of prior research effort.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The input energy for the water behind the dam comes from the energy of sunlight that evaporated the water at the surface of the earth.  The resulting water vapor rises up to a height where it condenses into clouds.  The heat of condensation (aka heat of vaporization) radiates to outer space, and at that point, the droplets that make up the cloud are much higher than they were before they were evaporated.  These droplets fall as rain and end up at a higher altitude than they started, providing the energy to turn the turbines at the dam.

Comment: The main reason to ask this question was that the electricity generated is not compromised in any way i.e is there any loss in the electricity generated or the whole electricity generated is passed to the grid.

Comment: @tank12, I don't quite understand your concern.  The hydro-turbines and generators each have their own efficiency rating, so some of the energy from the hydrostatic head of the water behind the dam turns into heat due to those inefficiencies, which is exactly what happens in ANY energy conversion process.

Answer (score 0):

[image: dam]

[This image shows](https://www.usgs.gov/special-topic/water-science-school/science/hydroelectric-power-how-it-works?qt-science_center_objects=0#qt-science_center_objects) how  a power generating system dam /turbine system works.

The [gravitational field](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Gravitational_potential) of the earth has a potential  :

> In classical mechanics, the gravitational potential at a location is equal to the work (energy transferred) per unit mass that would be needed to move an object to that location from a fixed reference location. It is analogous to the electric potential with mass playing the role of charge. The reference location, where the potential is zero, is by convention infinitely far away from any mass, resulting in a negative potential at any finite distance.

This means that masses high up have potential energy, which is released with falling. 
An object [falling from rest](http://hyperphysics.phy-astr.gsu.edu/hbase/flobj.html) from some height  arrives at the ground with kinetic energy:

[image: falling]

Fluids can be treated as mass in a given volume dV. The water in the dam is at rest at a certain height, when the sluice gates open, the flow of volume of water gains kinetic energy which is turned into electromagnetic energy by use of the turbines.

Comment: The main reason to ask this question was that the electricity generated is not compromised in any way i.e is there any loss in the electricity generated or the whole electricity generated is passed to the grid.

Comment: @tank12 then your question is wrongly phrased. The kinetic energy of the flow tunrs the turbines that generated electricity with some efficiency dependent on the engineering diagrams of the turbines,so it for is an engineering.se question. Energy will be lost in friction with the solid turbine mechanics, and in convection of water through the turbine, but it is always conserved if everything were added up. see this efficiency study https://www.sciencedirect.com/science/article/pii/S187661021735124X  to get an idea

Answer (score 0):

Because the generator spun by the turbine contains copper wire which has some electrical resistance, the current generated in it will heat the wire in the amount (I^2 x R) where I is the current and R is the resistance of all the wire. That heat represents an efficiency loss, which means that part of the potential energy represented by the high-pressure flow of water through the turbine is lost in heat.

These *I^2R* losses can be minimized by designing the coils of wire so as to generate the highest possible *voltage*; this minimizes the associated *current* and thereby increases the efficiency of the generator. This in turn requires the wire in the generator to be coated with insulation that can withstand the high voltage without breakdown at the operating temperature of the generator coils. With the passage of time, insulation technology has improved to the point where it makes sense to rewind the armatures in the generators of the oldest hydroelectric plants with better-insulated wire (and more of it, in a finer gauge) so as to generate power at significantly higher voltage with less loss. The generator armatures at Hoover Dam underwent such a refit in 1988.

By the way, a well-designed water turbine of modern manufacture (search on *Francis turbine*) is capable of efficiencies exceeding 95%, meaning that only 5% or less of the power in the flowing water is lost as turbulence or friction in the water or is unrecovered by the turbine and flows out with the discharge.